# Android firebase retrieve data in listview error

Tags: android, database, error-handling, firebase-realtime-database

i am stuck in my code to retrieve firebase data in listview using Model Class. I have to retrieve data in list view when i use String Class instead of Model Class so data is showing but when i use Model Class app is stopping and close

here is error given below.

```
 Process: com.example.daniyal.audioplayer, PID: 29475
                                                                             com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.daniyal.audioplayer.ModelData
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.adw.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.adw.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.example.daniyal.audioplayer.Songs$1.onDataChange(Songs.java:44)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.yk.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.aaf.zzIo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.aal.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

**My Activity to Retrieve Data**

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
ListView L1;
List<ModelData> list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_songs);
    L1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AllSongs);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("songs");


}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                ModelData Mod = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ModelData.class);
                list.add(Mod);
                System.out.println("DATA" + Mod.name);

            }

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Songs.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , list);
            L1.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

**Here is My ModelClass**

```
public class ModelData {

public String name;
public String link;

public ModelData(){}

public ModelData(String name, String link) {
    this.name = name;
    this.link = link;
}
```

}

[SEE IMAGE OF FIREBASE STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKl1v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use same ModelClass `ModelData` than try replacing one line:

Replace `databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("songs");`

To
`databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`

**OR**
Modify your Firebase code like below:

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        list.clear();
            // Removed for loop, because you are directly pointing to `songs` node and here you can directly get data by Mapping Your Model class
            ModelData Mod = dataSnapshot.getValue(ModelData.class);
            list.add(Mod);
            System.out.println("DATA" + Mod.name);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Songs.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , list);
        L1.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hey firoz , thanks i understand. you saved me just saying  "Removed for loop, because you are directly pointing to `songs` node" it helps me and i got it.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            list.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                HashMap<String, Object> task_map = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot1.getValue();

                list.add(new ModelData(task_map.get("name"), task_map.get("link"));
                System.out.println("DATA" + Mod.name);

            }

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Songs.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , list);
            L1.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: hey Mehual Kabaraia, thanks for the code i will try hashmap for now i just solved my problem. thanks for the reply:)